# Im triying to use a JLabel as a BackGround and I cant

Tags: java, swing

```java
f = new JFrame();
f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

d = new JPanel();
f.add(d);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jean\\Pictures\\988057.jpg");
JLabel background = new JLabel(icon);
background.setSize(d.getSize());
background.setLocation(0,0);
d.add(background);
d.setLayout(null);
background.setOpaque(true);

d.add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER, 0);
```

I'm trying to use a JLabel to display a background image but this code isn't working, despite the path to the image being correct. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `BorderLayout.CENTER` when your layout is null? Why are you using null layout to start with?

Comment: Suggestions: 1. First debug -- make sure that the path is right by displaying the ImageIcon in a JOptionPane. Just pass it in and see if it displays.  2. Better to get images as resources *not* as a file as you're trying to do.  Get the resource from the class, and lead in an image via `ImageIO.get(...)`. 3. You almost never should use null layouts. 4. To use an image as a background for a GUI, it is usually best to draw it inside of the paintComponent method of the background JPanel.

Comment: Really thanks. I will find out the problem. File file = new File("ruta/de/la/imagen.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

Comment: Large chunks of code in comments are illegible. If it's an answer, post an answer. If it's part of the question, edit the question.

Comment: [edit] your question with any new information please

Comment: to put it more drastically: null layout is __wrong__, always

Answer (score 1):

You are calling f.setVisible(true), before adding label and icons to it.
And you don't want to add panel in between label and fram.
You can try this approach,

```
            f = new JFrame();
            f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\jean\\Pictures\\988057.jpg");
            JLabel background = new JLabel();
            background.setIcon(icon);

            background.setSize(f.getSize());
            f.add(background);
            f.setVisible(true);
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I found the solution. Imagecon its not the best for work with Images. Im using  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);.

Comment: setSize is __wrong__ (because it's either useless or implies null layout which is wrong ;)

Answer (score -2):

The Solution. Thanks Guys.

```
    f = new JFrame();
    f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    
    d = new JPanel();
    d.setSize(f.getSize());
    f.add(d);   
    
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\jean\\Pictures\\988057.jpg");

    
    try {
        
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        label.setSize(d.getSize());
        d.add(label);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    }
```

Comment: You're still calling `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame *before* adding all components, you're still using files instead of resources, still setting sizes,... this is not an example of best practices or even good code, I'm afraid.